# I want my bot to recognize discord stickers in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image]

I want the Discord bot to recognize the 'sticker' above. How can I check?

Comment: Do you have any code to show? If the bot has access to memory and the file input streams, it could hash the sticker and save the output.

Comment: I agree with Dave, if you show your code that would be very useful.